# How to solve Paypal error #10413

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-express, paypal-standard

Note: There is no solution for this issue in SE.

PayPal gateway has rejected the request. The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts (#10413: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details).

```
2017-07-28T12:48:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [url] =><.......url.........>
    [SetExpressCheckout] => Array
        (
            [PAYMENTACTION] => Authorization
            [AMT] => 100.00
            [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
            [RETURNURL] => https://abcd.com/paypal/express/return/
            [CANCELURL] => https://abcd.com/paypal/express/cancel/
            [INVNUM] => *****
            [SOLUTIONTYPE] => Mark
            [GIROPAYCANCELURL] => https://abcd.com/paypal/express/cancel/
            [GIROPAYSUCCESSURL] => https://abcd.com/checkout/onepage/success/
            [BANKTXNPENDINGURL] => https://abcd.com/checkout/onepage/success/
            [LOCALECODE] => en_US
            [ITEMAMT] => 2.00
            [TAXAMT] => 0.00
            [SHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
            [BUSINESS] => 
            [NOTETEXT] => 
            [EMAIL] => abcd@gmail.com
            [FIRSTNAME] => abcd
            [LASTNAME] => 215
            [MIDDLENAME] => 
            [SALUTATION] => 
            [SUFFIX] => 
            [COUNTRYCODE] => country
            [STATE] => state
            [CITY] => city
            [STREET] => address
            [ZIP] => zip code
            [PHONENUM] => mobile
            [SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => IN
            [SHIPTOSTATE] => state
            [SHIPTOCITY] => city
            [SHIPTOSTREET] => address
            [SHIPTOZIP] => zip code
            [SHIPTOPHONENUM] => mobile
            [SHIPTOSTREET2] => 
            [STREET2] => 
            [SHIPTONAME] => name
            [ADDROVERRIDE] => 1
            [METHOD] => SetExpressCheckout
            [VERSION] => 72.0
            [USER] => ****
            [PWD] => ****
            [SIGNATURE] => ****
            [BUTTONSOURCE] => Magento_Cart_Community
        )

    [response] => Array
        (
            [TIMESTAMP] => 2017-07-28T12:48:59Z
            [CORRELATIONID] => **************
            [ACK] => Failure
            [VERSION] => 72.0
            [BUILD] => *******
            [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10413
            [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.
            [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.
            [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
        )

    [__pid] => 1928
)

2017-07-28T12:49:04+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [url] => ...url...
    [getPalDetails] => Array
        (
            [METHOD] => getPalDetails
            [VERSION] => 72.0
            [USER] => ****
            [PWD] => ****
            [SIGNATURE] => ****
            [BUTTONSOURCE] => Magento_Cart_Community
        )

    [response] => Array
        (
            [PAL] => ************
            [LOCALE] => en_GB
            [TIMESTAMP] => 2017-07-28T12:49:04Z
            [CORRELATIONID] => ***********
            [ACK] => Success
            [VERSION] => 72.0
            [BUILD] => **********
        )

    [__pid] => 1930
)
```

Comment: Please enable paypal log and compare each amount such as Subtotal, Tax, Shipping with your paypal log. if everything same the try the different payapal user acount. Paypal sometimes rejects same user accessing multiple times.

Comment: i just updated my question with log

Comment: there is no tax, shipping free, only product mrp

Comment: is product mrp  correct when compared your subtotal?

Comment: yes, my products mrp 100rs, and sudtotal mrp 100rs

Comment: Better you try different PayPal user. Sometimes PayPal account.